# iFrame link in <a href="link.html">

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I set up this link as below with  using **iFrame** but without a video itself but name e.g.

Interview video

Here is a iframe of have as below:

```
  <iframe width="400" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/G_G8SdXktHg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to in this as below:

```
    <div class="toogle_wrap_intro">
    <div class="trigger"><a href="#">Browse video categories</a></div>
    <div class="toggle_container_video">
        <ul class="lists_video">
        <li><a href="#"><a href="video/aps_production.mp4"><p>Interview video</span></p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is for iPhone and jQuery1.8.1. What is the correct way to set up a video link via  for a drop down menu and when a video finished playing it will go back to the same page.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorporate"?

Comment: Why are you setting an iframe to a video file?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are using a frame because you want to hold the video in a certain place?  I would suggest using the `<video>` tag in html5 instead of iframe.

```
<video width="400" height="225" controls="controls">
  <source src="video/aps_production.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

give the iframe an id and target it in the link's url: `iframe id="iframe"` and then append `#iframe` to the url of the document the link is in. `a href="url.html#iframe"`

Comment: Thank you albert. Can you put it together with example in code, please?

Comment: above is an example....without your url, i have no idea of knowing what it is....